# Rigid body motor constraint reversing when crossing the 90 degree angle on the Z axis

Tags: constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour on a rigid body simulation. First I'll explain my situation a little bit.

There is half a cube and a cylinder, both with an active rigid body. The cylinder is attached to the cube with a hinge rigid body constraint so it can rotate like a wheel. The cylinder also has motor constraint attached to another small cube (passive rigid body).

With this setup I would expect that the wheel keeps spinning in the same angular direction but it doesn't. In the animation below you can see that the angular rotation of the motor reverses when crossing the Y axis on the world axes.

http://s27.postimg.org/4jha0ugkh/mechani_small.gif

Any idea how I can overcome this problem? I just want the wheel to be spinning in one direction while dragging the cube along with it.

**UPDATE**

Bithur's solution works like a charm:

http://s10.postimg.org/6jhof0buv/mechani_02.gif

Here is the file:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the Object 2 to geo_body in the motor parameters seems to solve the problem
[image]

Comment: @wout glad to help, and thanks for the fixed animation :)